# Excel VBA: Conditional erase parts of worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, montecarlo

I have a workbook in structure not very unlike this one (but much more advanced):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UeGncSFijUM

That is :

(1)a worksheet where a row makes some calculations involving rand() and where the result value is carried over to the next row where a similar calculation is done and where the final result occur after a maximum of 250 rows.

(2)Excel then repeats this 250 calculation 20000 times

(3)and do some calculations on the 20000 independent results.

Much is done through functions and I use VBA mostly to control the flow of calculations.

All this takes some time and I try to optimize it all step by step.

Now the result of each (1) is likely to be reached much before row 250, on average row 125. I would like to erase the rest of the calculations if that condition is met at, say, row 125. Say call a VBA script through an if statement that erase the content of the rest of the cells.

Is it possible to call a VBA statement from a function?

Comment: You cannot call a macro from the worksheet but you can call a UDF function. However, a UDF cannot alter any cell but the cell that calls it. I suppose some sort of public boolean variable might halt a looping VBA operation and a UDf *could* change the state of that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best shot at some outside the box thinking.

Could you possibly use `Call Methodname` or  `CallByName(wsWorksheet, sMethodname, VbMethod, vOptionalVariantToPass)` on a worksheet_change event that checks for specific values resulting from your formulas?